# Окончание числительных во всплывающей подсказке кол-ва ответов по метке

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

При просмотре [списка лучших пользователей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) (надо заменить на "участников") по метке, во всплывающей подсказке кол-ва ответов неверное окончание числительных:

[image: 423]

[image: 141]

Судя по transifex множественных форм [не существует](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266091?key=7c75e69f3083cd4bca520c3622b27bf3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить разные формы в зависимости от числа.

Answer (score 0):

Придать сообщению иной вид, где окончание не будет зависеть от числа. Например:

> ответов опубликовано: $Total$